# How to enable grid decorations programmatically in QGIS3?

Tags: pyqgis, grids-graticules, gui

I'm developing a plugin that will enable the grid decorations(like copyright, scale bar) on the map canvas, but I don't find any clue on how to do it.

Just to clarify ***I don't want*** to create a grid inside a layer, I just want to enable the decorations grid as shown in the image below.

[image]

I've searched in the QGIS GUI and QgsMapCanvas API without any luck.

Comment: To draw the grid QGIS uses the`QgsDecorationGrid` class which is not exposed through the API. A workaround is well explained in [this](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/264604/access-modify-qgis-copyright-decoration-through-python) answer.
Here is another link to give you an idea of which project entries you need to write to enable the grid: https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/blob/master/src/app/decorations/qgsdecorationgrid.cpp#L152-L163

Comment: Thanks, @CodeBard, but the approach on the answer works when I save and reload the project. I need a workaround like in the [cheat sheet](https://docs.qgis.org/testing/en/docs/pyqgis_developer_cookbook/cheat_sheet.html#decorators), but for the QgsDecorationGrid. Unfortunately, I don't find yet what do I have to override in the grid render method to enable the grid without reloading the project.